# Filtering XML tags with attributes using Where-Object

Tags: xml, powershell

I'm having a XML similar to following and need to get `<Document>` nodes where`<ZZXMLT>` equals '04'.

```
<DataArea>
    <Document>
        <ZZPRTF>PMS241PF</ZZPRTF>
        <ZZXMLT Label="Variant">03</ZZXMLT>
    </Document>
    <Document>
        <ZZPRTF>PMS241PF</ZZPRTF>
        <ZZXMLT Label="Variant">04</ZZXMLT>
    </Document>
    <Document>
        <ZZPRTF>PMS242PF</ZZPRTF>
        <ZZXMLT Label="Variant">04</ZZXMLT>
    </Document>
</DataArea>
```

Following is the powershell code.

```
$xml = [xml](Get-Content -Path $file.FullName | Out-String)
$product = $xml.SelectSingleNode("//Document")
$parent = $product.ParentNode
$allproducts = @($parent.SelectNodes("Document") | Where-Object {$_.ZZXMLT -eq "04"})
```

This is working fine when `<ZZXMLT>` does not have an attribute but for the original XML there is an attribute.

Can somebody help me to get this done

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using PowerShell's Xml dot-notation and the `Where-Object` cmdlet:

```
$Xml = [xml]@'
<DataArea>
    <Document>
        <ZZPRTF>PMS241PF</ZZPRTF>
        <ZZXMLT Label="Variant">03</ZZXMLT>
    </Document>
    <Document>
        <ZZPRTF>PMS241PF</ZZPRTF>
        <ZZXMLT Label="Variant">04</ZZXMLT>
    </Document>
    <Document>
        <ZZPRTF>PMS242PF</ZZPRTF>
        <ZZXMLT Label="Variant">04</ZZXMLT>
    </Document>
</DataArea>
'@

$Xml.DataArea.Document |Where-Object { $_.ZZXMLT.'#Text' -eq '04' }
```

```
ZZPRTF   ZZXMLT
------   ------
PMS241PF ZZXMLT
PMS242PF ZZXMLT
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't need `Where-Object` for this - you can describe a `<Document>` node with a descendant `<ZZXMLT>` node with the text contents `04` in the XPath expression passed to `SelectNodes`:

```
$allproducts = $xml.SelectNodes("/DataArea/Document[./ZZXMLT[text()='04']]")
```

Comment: Hi @Mathias Thank you for the answer. Is it not possible from cmdlet method is it not possible? Your answer is working fine. I'm asking just to get an idea